# ms access vba: sorting is not working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to sort the elements of a field manually without using any built in function. Below is my code

```
    Function Test(myval As Variant) As Variant
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim arr() As Double
        Dim arr_lenght As Long
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim temp As Double
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim Index As Integer

        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Salary (t) Total] FROM SalaryT")

        count = 1
        Index = 0
        rst.MoveFirst

        Do While Not rst.EOF
            On Error Resume Next
            arr(count) = CDbl(rst![Salary (t) Total])
            count = count + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop

        arr_length = UBound(arr) - 1

'This is my sorting algorithm

        For i = 1 To arr_length
            For j = (i + 1) To arr_length
                   If arr(i) < arr(j) Then
                    temp = arr(i)
                    arr(i) = arr(j)
                    arr(j) = temp
                   End If
            Next j
        Next i

        For k = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(k) = CDbl(myval ) Then
                Index = k
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k

        Test = Index     
    End Function
```

This always output 0 since I set the Index at the beginning 0. But in the last for loop I change the Index value with the value of K and it looks like it is not changing the value. What is wrong with this code. Please help me to fix it. Thanks.

Some example data from SalaryT:

```
ID  Name           Salary (t) Total 
1   test name1       55,234.30
2   test name2       2,322.29
```

Salary (t) Total save the values as text. And later in arr array I take those values and keep them as Double value.

myval send a value from Salary (t) Total column. So some example function call could be

```
Test(55,234.30)
Test(2,322.29)
```

Comment: Can you post example data?  What is the value of myval?  What are some of the example data from SalaryT?

Comment: You have a lot issues it seems to me.  Get rid of `On Error Resume Next`.  You aren't ever initiating the array.  You get a error and then ignore it.  That's an important error you've ignored.  You have to ReDim it at some point to set the size.  Another thing I see is this line looks off `arr_length = UBound(arr) - 1`  In a base 0 system the array length would be 1 more than the Ubound, not 1 less.

Comment: for testing change dim arr() as double to dim arr(2) as double, or arr(3) since you're not starting the array until 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not in your sort, but in your assignment to the array. You don't initialize the elements of the array. If you take out the line:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

you see the function fails at:

```
arr(count) = CDbl(rst![Salary (t) Total])
```

with the error "Subscript out of range".

if you add a subscript to your dim arr() it works as intended. If you don't know the size of the  array you can count the records first then redim your variable. (or just wait to declare it until after you count the records.  I know you could use rst.Countrecords, but my experience with it has been sketchy at best, i prefer to count the records some other way, this is only one quick example.)

```
count = 0
rst!movefirst
do while not rst.EOF
    count = count + 1
loop
redim arr(count) as double
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known Array sort algorithm available form `Chip Pearson's` website.

All you have to do is download the Module that has the sorting algorithm on his [site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx) and then add it to your project.

Then you can simply pass in an array and it will return the sorted array back to you.